# OpenGL Light changes : Ambient to Diffuse or Specular works but not the opposite

Tags: opengl, light

I'm having troubles with the lights in OpenGL :

I change le light of my ball with this piece of code :

```
switch(option) {                                            
case ambient:                                               
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_AMBIENT,lum_ambient);              
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_SPECULAR,mat_ambient);           
  break;                                                    
case diffuse:                                               
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_DIFFUSE,lum_diffuse);              
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_DIFFUSE,mat_diffuse);            
  break;                                                    
case specular:                                              
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_SPECULAR,lum_speculaire);          
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_SPECULAR,mat_speculaire);        
  break;                                                    
}
```

I can change from Ambient, to diffuse or specular. But once I changed, i can't go back to ambient and worse : to go back to diffuse I need to call the ambient.

And I don't think it comes from this piece of code :

```
   switch (key) {                              
   case 27:                                    
       exit(1);                                
   case '1':                                   
     option = ambient;                         
     glutPostRedisplay();                      
     break;                                    
   case '2':                                   
     option = diffuse;                         
     glutPostRedisplay();                      
     break;                                    
   case '3':                                   
     option = specular;                        
     glutPostRedisplay();                      
     break;                                    
   }
```

Any idea where my problems come from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that state doesn't go away just because you changed some *other* state. If you have two global variables:

```
int x;
int y;
```

Changing `y` does not affect `x`. If you have this switch statement:

```
switch(option)
{
case ambient:
  x = 4;
  break;
case diffuse:
  y = 6;
  break;
...
}
```

If you execute this with `diffuse`, and then execute it with `ambient`, what is the value of `y`? It's *still 6*. Of course it is, because you didn't change it.

There is no "ambient", "diffuse", or "specular" lighting in OpenGL. Each of these are just different terms in the lighting model for each light. That is, OpenGL always does *all of these* for each light. The reason you don't see any effect from the specular lighting component is because the initial specular material color is *zero*. This produces a zero specular lighting component.

Once you change the specular material color, it will remain that new value until you change it again. If you want to "turn off" the specular lighting, then you need to reset the specular material color to zero. The same goes for the others.

---

You're trying to toggle between your settings and the default settings for the three lighting models. So you have to actually do that: you have to reset the values to the OpenGL defaults. Those are found in the OpenGL specification.

You do have to set the light intensity(ies) in addition to the material color though.

If you don't want to look through the spec, here are the defaults:

- ambient light: `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`
- ambient material: `(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0)`
- diffuse light: `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` (only for light0. All other lights default to `(0.0 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`
- diffuse material: `(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0)`
- specular light: `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` (only for light0. All other lights default to  `(0.0 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`
- specular material: `(0.0 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`

Comment: I starting to understand. But do I have to reset the glMaterial or the glLight or both ?

Comment: @Matthieu: *ahem* "If you want to 'turn off' the specular lighting, then you need to reset the specular ***material*** color to zero."

Comment: Well that's what I did, but get a black ball with my ambiant light and the specular light. (I reset GL_DIFFUSE to 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler: Sorry, see my edit. I forgot that OpenGL's lighting model was pants-on-head stupid. Really, switch to shaders; you'll be doing everyone a favor.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use different lights and not only Light0. Also, try turning all the light off before turning a new one up using :

```
glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
```

Some help : [Light source - OPENGL](http://www.falloutsoftware.com/tutorials/gl/gl8.htm)